# How to get FileSize of or start reading at a particular point in files in ipod-library?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, assets

I'm trying to implement, more or less, lstat (to get filesize and extention) and fseek workalikes for the music files in the ipod-library and assets-library.  I'm then streaming these files to players (might be on this device, might not).

I've come up with three approaches, but neither is particularly satisfying:

1) to mimic lstat to tell the size of the file, use AVAssetReader to read additional chunks of the file, adding the length of these chunks to a variable until done.  At the end of the loop, the variable now contains the length of the file.

To 'fseek', using an AVAssetReader, you start from the beginning of the file, and read until you get to the desired point.  Then you cache the bit of the file you might have left, and save it for when the fread happens.

2) Using AVAssetExportSession, you copy the given file to your Documents directory, and then you can do whatever you need to do with it (real lstat, fseek, etc).  The downside is the 5-20 second pause depending on the size of the file.

So, it seems I have my app do a lot of extra work (#1), or a force the user to wait 5-20 seconds between each song.  Just seems wasteful.

3) With ALAsset, you can get the size of the representation...(but that doesn't work for audio files), and certainly doesn't address fseek.

I'm currently using #2.  It definitely feels slow, but then again, it does work, after a fashion.

Can anyone else tell me a better approach?

Thanks,

-Ken